# Randomly display files in survey block in Qualtrics

Tags: qualtrics

I am attempting to randomly loop through ~1400 mp4 files in a Qualtrics survey. Each respondent would see one of these files. I understand how to do this for images, using a Loop and Merge and:

```
img src="https://survey.qualtrics.com/ControlPanel/Graphic.php?IM=${lm://Field/1}"
```

However, the Field/1 links to the Qualtrics IDs that are in the image library and mp4's are in the files library. I do not know where to find those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little bit of a pain, but first click one of the files and View it. The URL at the top will have the ID at the very end. Go back to your list and open the inspect tool. Search for the ID. The first one you find is a large list of text. They are all in there.